# the updated content can not shown on the screen when i use tail -f command

Tags: linux, tomcat, tail

When I use the 'tail -f catalina.out' command to continuously monitor the content of  a log file,  the updated content is not showing on the screen. But when create a symbolic link to the log file, the new file name is aa.log, the command -'tail -f aa.log' does work correctly.

Can any one know the reason of this symptom or explain why this happen?

Comment: My OS is CentOS release 6.7

Comment: does it work if you use `tail ---disable-inotify -f catalina.out` ?

Comment: The file "catalina.out" is generated by Tomcat, I've added that tag for reference purposes. What are you doing exactly with Tomcat while you are monitoring that file?

Comment: the command-'tail ----disable-inotify -f catalina.out' does work well for me. Thanks.